# cannot access page that use html in js in iframe with DOM error

Tags: iframe

here I have a site www.mytest.com, it is very simple that only one blank page with an iframe.

```
<div id="container">
Hello World!!!
</div>
<div>
<iframe style="border: none;height: 100%;width:100%;position: fixed;top: 50px; background:white" src="http://anothersite.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

I have set Content-Security-Policy in "anothersite.com", and set it allow be accessed by site "www.mytest.com". It works fine, and in mytest.com iframe I could access "anothersite.com" and do normal things.

But, when I trying to access one page of "anothersite.com" in the iframe, it report an error: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://anothersite.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

that is because I wrote these code for this page:

```
var test = '<div class="mystyle"><span>mythings</span></div> ......';
```

I have tried set document.domain = mytest.com in first site. And log for iframe's domain

```
console.log("iframeData",document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.domain);
console.log("hostName", window.location.hostname);
```

both of these result are "www.mytest.com". But it still cannot access the special page with same error.

Anyone know how to solve it or any workround for this?

Comment: I also tried set <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> in anothersite.com, it still cannot help.

Comment: another thing is that mytest.com and othersite.com has no any interaction. All requests are by othersite.com itself.